# Object created from a class to be used within a function prints unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)

Tags: php, class

Im trying to create a class that I can request to return a variable based on some mobile detection. Im trying to avoid defining anything with `global`. I'm getting the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)`

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/Mobile_Detect.php';

class detectDevice {
  private static $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
  private static $deviceType;

  public static function returnDevice(){

    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
      $deviceType = "IS MOBILE";
    }
    if( $detect->isTablet() ){
      $deviceType = "IS TABLET";
    }

    print self::$deviceType;
  }
}

echo detectDevice::returnDevice();
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't instantiate classes when declaring member variables. Do it in your constructor or in another method.

Comment: in your static function add `if (!isset(self::$detect)) self::$detect = new Mobile_Detect;` before the first if and take the assignment out of the property definition.